# Boost fusion and runtime collection growing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I have

```
boost::fusion::vector<> args;
args = boost::fusion::push_back(args, 100);
std::cout << boost::fusion::size(args) << std::endl;
```

The cout shows me size equals to 0.

View code here: [cpp.sh/3xcwsi](http://cpp.sh/3xcwsi)

Can I have any non associative boost fusion container which can be altered at runtime and stored at the same variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The whole concept of the Fusion Library deals in statically typed “containers” - actually just abstractions over sequences.

What you are looking for is likely in the Boost Container library though. It has stable_vector, static_vector and small_vector, among others.

These van also be used to underly ordered/associative containers from Boost Container